# What is the risk of updating Registry settings programatically?

Tags: c#, windows, internet-explorer, winapi, registry

I am trying to change the proxy settings to Enabled/Disabled for Internet Explorer programatically using C#. This to toggele between web sites that would require proxy or not.

My Code:

```
string key = "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Internet Settings";

RegistryKey RegKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(key, true);
RegKey.SetValue("ProxyEnable", 1);
```

Most articles I referred to for updating the registry indicate there is a risk of doing so.

I want to know

1. What are the risks involved in executing the above code
2. Is there any mitigation I can do to cover the risks. For example, taking a registry backup for the particular key.

Comment: The only "risk" I can think of is that Internet Explorer might suddenly decide to put its registry keys elsewhere... registry editing isn't just dangerous by nature, and especially not programmatically, when you've tested it.

Comment: Yeah no more risk than editing manually. Just make sure you have/make a backup in case you want to rollback. As with anything else!

Comment: That's global so would affect all instances of IE? Those settings are configurable via the `InternetSetOption` + `INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION ` + one of the proxy flags which is the safe, abstracted way to do it.

Comment: Biggest issue is the user having no clue whatsoever why the browser doesn't work properly.  Induced in no small part by you using the wrong way to do this.  Update the proxy exclusion list instead.

Comment: Also, if you update the registry directly, you don't really know when your setting change takes effect. Many settings are cached, and changing the registry has no effect until the cache is refreshed.

Answer (score 1):

The risk of changing the registry is simply that you can damage the system. If you really want to run it on a customers machine:

- Read all the documentation you can find about the registry entries you change
- Take into account that different windows versions and different product versions may have different registry entries
- Ask someone who ever changed these values
- Make sure your application will have the permission to do this (say: run as administrator, which should not be done for regular usage. Only for instance in an installer).
- Make sure you can uninstall the changes

Answer (score 1):

The registry is an environment that is controlled by the OS and may be subject of unexpectable updates from it. I think that the main risk is to be unable to know what really happens with your data (for example : if Windows thinks it is a good idea to reset or overwrite your values, you lose it all).

Also, like someone said in a comment to another answer, invalid entries may lead to data loss, especially if your data exceeds the maximum length allowed by the registry.

If you need to modify the registry, you may test if the key do exist and keep trace of original values before overwriting. Of course, you need to be sure that altering the key won't have unexpected effects.

Comment: I was actually quoting the first part of that answer and lampshading the extreme dissonance between the two sentences.